# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault using array

Tags: c++

I am getting a segmentation fault when running my program and also getting a weird result. I have put a lot of debug code in to find exactly where the weird behavior is.

```
int det_2b2(int d[2][2])
{
    cout<<d[1][1]<<","<<d[1][2]<<endl;
    cout<<d[2][1]<<","<<d[2][2]<<endl;
    cout<<(d[1][1]*d[2][2]-d[1][2]*d[2][1])<<endl;
     return (d[1][1]*d[2][2]-d[1][2]*d[2][1]);
}

int det_3b3(int d3[3][3])
{
    int r1;
    int x[2][2];
    x[1][1]=d3[2][2];
    x[1][2]=d3[2][3];
    x[2][1]=d3[3][2];
    x[2][2]=d3[3][3];
    cout<<"r1.1="<<det_2b2(x)<<endl;
    r1=det_2b2(x);
    cout<<"r1.2="<<r1<<endl;
    x[1][1]=d3[2][1];
    x[2][2]=35;
    cout<<"r1.3="<<r1<<endl;
    x[1][2]=d3[2][3];
    cout<<"r1.4="<<r1<<endl;
    x[2][1]=d3[3][1];
    cout<<"r1.5="<<r1<<endl;
    x[2][2]=d3[3][3];
    cout<<"r1.6="<<r1<<endl;
    int r2=det_2b2(x);
    x[1][1]=d3[2][1];
    x[1][2]=d3[2][2];
    x[2][1]=d3[3][1];
    x[2][2]=d3[3][2];
    int r3=det_2b2(x);
    cout<<r1<<endl;
    cout<<d3[1][1]<<endl;
    cout<<r1*d3[1][1]<<endl;
    cout<<r2*d3[1][2]<<endl;
    cout<<r3*d3[1][3]<<endl;
    return r1*d3[1][1]-r2*d3[1][2]+r3*d3[1][3];
}
```

When I set the value of x[2][2] = 35 or x[2][2]= d[3][3] it changes the value of r1 to 35 or to the value in d[3][3] so there is definitely something wrong under the covers. The calling program is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[3][3];
    a[1][1] =   1;
    a[1][2] =   2;
    a[1][3] =   3;
    a[2][1] =   4;
    a[2][2] =   5;
    a[2][3] =   6;
    a[3][1] =   7;
    a[3][2] =   8;
    a[3][3] =   9;
    cout << "DET a= " << det_3b3(a)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs at the end of the calling program well after the program error occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are accessing arrays ot of bounds. Indexing for `int a[N]` starts at `a[0]` and the biggest index is `a[N-1]`.

Comment: As ideas go, perhaps learning the language (from a book) wouldn't hurt....

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ are indexed from `0`, not `1`. Any access to `a[x][3]` in `main`, for example is out of bounds.

Just subtract `1` from all of your indices and it should compile, but you should read an [introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and learn about loops and aggregate initialization.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an array of size `nXn`, then the possible indices are from (0,0) to (n-1,n-1).

Therefore,

`a[1][1]` should be `a[0][0]`, and so on.

So the last element would be `a[2][2]` (for 3 X 3 matrix), not `a[3][3]`